# Org-mode question: Evaluating lisp in property

Tags: org-mode, text-properties

Is there a way to evaluate (during an export) lisp code inside a property? If yes, what’s the syntax?

For instance, like in this dummy example:

```
* Header
:PROPERTIES:
:EXPORT_FILE_NAME: (print “filename.txt”)
:END:
```

I tried this but it doesn’t work.

Comment: Property values are just strings IIRC: they have no special properties and although you could evaluate them manually if they happen to be a legal elisp expression, there is no provision in Org mode to do any such thing on export, let alone replace them with their value. See https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-syntax.html#Node_Properties

Comment: I see, thanks. In my case I wished to automatically set EXPORT_FILE_NAME to a string deduced from the heading title, using lisp. Since I use ox-hugo (for HUGO export) that EXPORT_FILE_NAME property must be set like this so that the heading is valid for export.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to do what you want. I took the liberty of expanding the export_file_name to resemble what I think you implied in the comments above. I don't think this is the best way to do what you want though. It isn't necessary to put the code in the properties, and it would be simpler to just put it in the list code that I put in the build section. If you do this a lot, e.g. for a blog post, I would wrap that into an interactive command you could use.

Anyway, the idea is to wrap this in a copy of the buffer, modify the buffer (here with org-map entries, but you could find other ways to do it) with that property, and then call the export in the copy. I use this code block by simply executing it, and a new buffer opens up to the file name "Header-for-something.txt".

```
* Header for something
   :PROPERTIES:
   :EXPORT_FILE_NAME: (concat (string-join (split-string (cl-fifth (org-heading-components))) "-") ".txt")
   :END:


** build                                                           :noexport:

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results none
(org-export-with-buffer-copy
 (org-map-entries
  (lambda ()
    (let ((efn (org-entry-get (point) "EXPORT_FILE_NAME")))
      (when (stringp efn)
    (org-entry-put (point) "EXPORT_FILE_NAME" (eval (read (string-trim efn))))))))
 (org-open-file (org-ascii-export-to-ascii nil t)))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
```